# How can I return a stable time taken by a function to execute

Tags: javascript, performance, function, time

I know that following code in javascript returning execute time of a function:

```
(function(){
    for(let i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
    }

    console.log(performance.now());
})()
```

But it returned a **Unstable result** and can I reach to a stable execute time? *(for a function or Code snippet)*

*Unstable result like this*:

> 850672.7449999889
>
> 852057.6050000091
>
> 853179.7950000037
>
> 1043505.1950000052

What is the reason for the return of this unstable value and is it rational to reach a static result?

Comment: Other things are happening in the browser at the same time, and other processes are running on the computer.  In a multi-threaded process with event/message interrupts you should never expect any one function in one thread to have a fixed execution time.  You should look at the range of times.  Depending on program logic the median or maximum times might be more important.

Comment: @DaveS has it right or, in direct answer to your question.  1) can I reach ... a stable execution time? -- pretty much no, even if you have 100% total control of all activity on your local system. A system admin wiz might get closer than any of us!  2) what is the reason for the return of this unstable value? -- other activity on your system, both other activity in the browser, and other o/s processes;  3) is it rational to reach a static result? -- not really, no. sha1's answer is pretty reasonable in that regard. Take an average. be happy!

Comment: @DaveS Thanks buddy! Now with that in mind (I means that the execution time is not reliable), What is the best way to measure execute time and is it there at all? (For example, to say that our program takes X time from the system)

Comment: There isn't an easy way to get one single perfect time on a modern PC, too much else is going on.@DavidConrad's comment below makes sense.  Discard highest and lowest, average the rest for a rough idea.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you can average the results you receive. The results should stabilize after some measurements and you can try different values, i.e., average of 10, 20...

However, `performance.now()` returns the elapsed time since the beginning of the lifetime of the document. Unless I am missing something, you should take the difference of two calls to this function; as in [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now#Example):

```
var t0 = performance.now();
doSomething();
var t1 = performance.now();
console.log("Call to doSomething took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.");
```

Comment: That does assume nothing else is happening so I'd still expect some variation.  Also per Mozilla docs: "It's important to keep in mind that to mitigate potential security threats such as Spectre, browsers typically round the returned value by some amount in order to be less predictable."

Comment: I would throw out the outliers (highest and lowest values) and then average the rest.